# Why am I unable to display attribute data in map?

Tags: javascript, geojson, popup

In the JSON file I have an attribute called `FairValue` which belongs to the polygon feature class. Similarly there is another attribute called `Survey_Num`. I want to display both these attributes on click on the polygon. My code is returning me latlng. I am new to Leaflet maps.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;margin:0;>
<head>    
    <title>Realestate Map:data </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:/Temp/lib/leaflet/leaflet.css">

    <script src="D:/Temp/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="D:/Temp/lib/leaflet/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="D:/Temp/data/realestate_plotskdk.json"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {height:100px;}</style>
</head>

<h1> REALESTATE MAP OF KODAKARA</h1>

<body style="height:100%;margin:0;">
    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:100%;background: #ADD8E6;margin:0"></div>      

    <script type="text/javascript">                     

        var map = L.map('map').setView([10.37227,76.30528], 8);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{maxZoom: 20, subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']}).addTo(map);

        var popup=L.popup();

        function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent( e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(map);
        }

        map.on('click', onMapClick);    

        var realestateLayer=L.geoJson(realestate).addTo(map);

        var marker = L.marker([10.37227,76.30528]).addTo(map);

        map.fitBounds(realestateLayer.getBounds());

        function setColor(FairValue){
            return FairValue > 1000000 ? '#a50f15' :
                FairValue > 500000 ?  '#de2d26' :
                FairValue > 100000 ?  '#fb6a4a' :
                FairValue > 10000 ?   '#fcae91' :
                                      '#90EE90'; 
        };

        function style(feature) {
            return {
               fillColor: setColor(feature.properties.FairValue),
               fillOpacity: 0.7,
               weight: 2,
               opacity: 1,
               color: '#ffffff',
               dashArray: '3' };
        };  

    </script>     

</body>
```

Please see my GeoJSON file as well.

```
var realestate = {
 "type":"FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
   {
     "type":"Feature",
     "geometry": {
       "type":"Polygon",
       "coordinates": [
         [[76.30078397600005,10.383036638000021],[76.30085359100008,10.38304938300007],[76.30089127100007,10.383120709000025],[76.30090889900004,10.383514486000024],[76.30093365800008,10.383662224000034],[76.30095862400003,10.383732806000069],[76.30100242500004,10.383816178000075],[76.30103375900006,10.383854675000066],[76.30108402000008,10.383861315000047],[76.30114685400008,10.383861634000027],[76.30117114800004,10.384135792000052],[76.30115798500003,10.38429413700004],[76.30119521600005,10.384370216000036],[76.30128842000005,10.384490687000039],[76.30138773400006,10.384598384000071],[76.30149346800005,10.384655739000038],[76.30159289000005,10.384706744000027],[76.30171725100007,10.384745397000074],[76.30186659100008,10.384765465000044],[76.30200979300008,10.38476670800003],[76.30201052800004,10.384645111000054],[76.30205277300007,10.384428712000044],[76.30207662500004,10.384053115000029],[76.30207853700006,10.383848214000068],[76.30202026400008,10.383636548000027],[76.30200426800008,10.383252197000047],[76.30186367600004,10.383220550000033],[76.30189988100005,10.383131806000051],[76.30206097700005,10.382752502000073],[76.30190008900007,10.382694523000055],[76.30172304500007,10.382700387000057],[76.30162769600008,10.382631821000075],[76.30160776300005,10.382600129000025],[76.30139475700008,10.382570280000039],[76.30113538200004,10.382562547000077],[76.30079948500008,10.382587296000054],[76.30078397600005,10.383036638000021]]
       ]
     },
     "properties": {
       "OBJECTID":1,
       "SHAPE_Leng":0.00644506804805,
       "SHAPE_Area":0.00000210973442692,
       "Survey_Num":684,
       "FairValue":240000,
       "Criteria_1":"WetLand(684/1,684/2,684/3)",
       "MainRoadAc":"N",
       "PrivateRoa":"",
       "NoRoadAcce":"",
       "Government":"",
       "WetLand_1":"Rs30,000(684/2),",
       "Water_Logg":"",
       "FairValue_":97165.9919028,
       "Type_plot":0
     }
   },
 ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to use code formatting on code, JSON, and anything else made more legible by fixed-width formatting; just use the `{}` button. Please also remember to describe the problem being encountered.

Comment: It is returning lat lng because  you pass in `e.latlng.toString()` to the `setContent()` method of your popup. Also, the click event is on your map. It should be on the geojson layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onEachFeature option of the GeoJSON to call a function which builds the popup content based on the properties (attributes) of the feature being clicked.

Try something like this:

```
var realestateLayer=L.geoJson(realestate, {onEachFeature:showAttributes}).addTo(map);                                   

map.fitBounds(realestateLayer.getBounds());

function showAttributes(json, lyr) {
    var att = json.properties;
    lyr.bindPopup("Fair value: " + att.FairValue + " Survey number: " + att.Survey_Num);
}
```

Notice the function name is passed in to the 'onEachFeature' option **without** parentheses `()`. As it is an options object it must be enclosed in `{}`.

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you very much . It worked. Hundred hugs!.Matt, I am speechless and dumb with happiness.

Comment: I'm very glad to help. If you are satisfied with the answer, could you please mark it as correct to close the question? Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, I marked it.